# Connect signed cookie parsing falsy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, node.js-connect

I'm having problems while trying to parse back signed cookies in express/connect application.

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    if(handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
        var signedCookies = cookie.parse(decodeURIComponent(handshakeData.headers.cookie));
        handshakeData.cookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(signedCookies, secret);
    } else {
        return accept('No cookie transmitted', false);
    }
    callback(null, true); // error first callback style 
});
```

What happens is call to `connect.utils.parseSignedCookies` returns empty object. I looked into source for parse function and found out that it calls unsign method which gets a substring of encoded value and then tries to sign it again with the same secret and compare the results to verify that its the same value encoded and for some reasons it fails and values does not match. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, why those values differs and why I'm unable to get correct session ID.

My app initialization code looks like this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser(secret));
app.use(express.session({
    key: 'sessionID',
    secret: secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient
    })
}));
```

Please help and point what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie parser is a middleware, so we have to use it like one. It will actually populate the object that you pass to it. This is how you would want to be using the parser:

```
// we need to use the same secret for Socket.IO and Express
var parseCookie = express.cookieParser(secret);

io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
  if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
    // pass a req, res, and next as if it were middleware
    parseCookie(handshake, null, function(err) {
      // use handshake.signedCookies, since the
      // cookie parser has populated it
    });
  } else {
    return accept('No session.', false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
});
```

The cookie parser API changed and this is what it looks like now:

```
module.exports = function cookieParser(secret) {
  return function cookieParser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies) return next();
    var cookies = req.headers.cookie;

    req.secret = secret;
    req.cookies = {};
    req.signedCookies = {};

    if (cookies) {
      try {
        req.cookies = cookie.parse(cookies);
        if (secret) {
          req.signedCookies = utils.parseSignedCookies(req.cookies, secret);
          req.signedCookies = utils.parseJSONCookies(req.signedCookies);
        }
        req.cookies = utils.parseJSONCookies(req.cookies);
      } catch (err) {
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      }
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

So what we're doing is passing `handshake` as a request object, and the parser will read the `headers.cookie` property. Then, the cookies will be parsed, and put into `req.signedCookies`. Since we passed `handshake` as `req`, the cookies are now in `handshake.signedCookies`. Note that the cookies are only signed because you passed a `secret` to the parser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this way makes more sense to do it but unfortunately it does not work either for some reasons. Here is a screenshot of the signed and re-signed values - it still differs: http://grab.by/qyra I don't really know what to do else...

Comment: The code is almost same as yours for the parsing part. But I'm not sure tho if I add it as a middle-ware correctly. It goes before session middle-ware and before router middle-ware. I will try to post whole code later when I get home, maybe there will be any ideas..

Comment: God damn it, seems that everything was fine all the time. The problem is that I used IP address while connecting to socketio server while I had browser opened on http://localhost. This resulted in the wrong cookie being sent to server when socket handshake request was sent... Stupid me..

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems left and right with cookies/sessions/socket.io etc. It was finally @vytautas comment that helped me. In case anyone sees this, please make sure you're connecting  to the correct host, whether you have it setup as localhost or an IP address or what have you. Otherwise you won't be able to parse your incoming cookies.

(Seems kind of obvious in hindsight.)